# What does the word "adidum" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

In a book in Latin, I found the sentence "Adidum vina" — Something (?) the wines. What does "adidum" mean?

[image: adidum vina]

Comment: Just those two words, no other context?

Comment: This is on signboard for a bar, a taberna. Moreover it appears several times in the book, so I think it's not a typo.

Comment: What book is this, if I may ask?

Comment: The book is "Falx aurea" - translated into latin by Rubricastellanus

Comment: @cnread Quite the translation of "Chez le joyeux Arverne"  The lettering is off, this word belongs on the upper line written in larger letters, see [the original](https://img.ricardostatic.ch/t_1000x750/pl/1192805892/0/4/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to information that I found on the [official Asterix site](https://www.asterix.com), the name in the original French is *Chez le Joyeux Arverne*, in English *Merry Arvernian*, referring to the Arverni, a people in southeast Gaul.

My 1982 edition of the Latin translation, published by DELTA, gives the word in question as *Madidum*, which means 'wet' and, by extension, 'drunk/inebriated/tipsy,' which makes sense in the context of a tavern. Moreover, the typeface and layout make clear that the word is meant to be in the first line of the sign, modifying *Arvernum* as part of the tavern's actual name ('At the House/Place of Business of the Drunken Arvernian').

[image: Apud Arvernum Madidum sign]